# Text File Processing in Java: Which will be more logical to perform?

Tags: java, file-io

i have to search and copy files from total of 1.8 million files.
here is what i have to do:

i have 40 filename in an array and 18,00,000 files in a folder.

what is a good option to perform?

```
a) pick one file from folder (having 1.8 millions), and loop through 40 files. 

OR

b) pick one filename from array and loop through 1.8 million files.
```

i have to search and copy those files which contain filename (present in array) that are to be matched in those 1.8 million files.

please guide me, with reasons.

Comment: Have you tried either option? Have you tried anything? What exactly are your concerns with either option? Unfortunately, we are not here to do your work for you. We will help you with specific issues you come across while you are *attempting* to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have 1.8 million files in array or in the folder? What is the  18,00,000? What is the array? If files are not too long it is always better to load them in memory.

Comment: @Jesse Webb i just want to know what would be more efficient , either option 'a' OR 'b' ...

Comment: Making your question more clear will get you good answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My tips:

1) Split the files in the folder. Most filesystems do not like so much in one folder.

2) Can't you put your data into a DB? Even if not structured - at least blobs...

3) your option 1) seems to promise better performance, because traversing dir structure is more expensive than comparing a string (it's a system call).

But better would be:

Go trough all files at once, put their **CRC32 hash into a Map**, and then check against the 40 files in the list. In other words, build up the meta data based on which you compare the "copy files" (by which I guess you mean exact copies) and look up in the Map by these meta data..

I hope I understood the question well.

Comment: those files are already divided into thousand's of folders ..

Comment: You say that there is 18,00,000 files in a folder. You seem do not control over what you say.

Comment: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileNameFilter

```
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] toCopy = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        //Make a trie or a hash of fileNames mapping to the required files
        boolean success = isRequired(fileName, directory);
            return success;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have

1. A directory structure with total 1.8 million files.
2. An Array with
   40 strings.

Now task is to find files with names *containing* and may not be exact matching any string from your Array of 40 and then process them.

I would suggest, build a search index on your file name list of 1.8 million and then query it 40 times. You can use [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) for this, but even a simple DB would also suffice.